# FSM: next state precedence

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fsm, state-machine, operator-precedence

When being in a state "a1" how can I show that the next arrows will have a precedence over each other, without having an overhead of extra states?

Full example:

- We are at **`a1`** state and signals **`x && y`** are asserted: we go to state b1
- If that condition is not asserted but **`x && z`** is asserted then we go to state b2
- If the above conditions are not asserted but **`x`** is asserted then we go to state b3

Visual concept:

[image]

In the above "FSM" we can't see that **`x && y`** is checked before the other two.

Code snippet:

```
always_comb begin
  case (states)
    a1: begin
      if (x && y)
        next_state = b1;
      else if (x && z)
        next_state = b2;
      else if (x)
        next_state = b3;
      else
        next_state = a1;
    end
  endcase
end
```

Comment: Is the question how to draw the digram correctly rather than code it?

Comment: The third transition, probably should be labelled as `X && !y && !z` and the second priority should be `x && y && !z` I do not think there is a from for noting precedence in a state diagram.

Comment: @Morgan Yes the question is mostly about the diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'd need to cover all the possible combinations of input events in each state to get a proper DFA (deterministic FSM).

However, you can get away by fully specifying the *triggers* in terms of input signals, and let your HDL default to "no transition".  In that case:

- transition from `a1` to `b1` may be triggered by `x &&  y && !z`
- transition from `a1` to `b2` may be triggered by `x && !y &&  z`
- transition from `a1` to `b3` may be triggered by `x && !y && !z`

(with `!` denoting logical 'not').

With an alphabet of 3 symbols (your three input signals), you get 2^3 = 8 possible combinations in every state.  Ask yourself: in your current design, what happens if all of `x`, `y` and `z` get asserted ?  You need to be specific about that.

**EDIT**

Let me be more specific.

Let's consider `A`, `B`, `C`, ... `H` as events, each representing one possible combination of input signals, such as:

```
  x y z
A 0 0 0
B 0 0 1
C 0 1 0
D 0 1 1
E 1 0 0
F 1 0 1
G 1 1 0
H 1 1 1
```

Then try to express your transitions in terms of `A`, `B`, `C`, ... `H`.  If you can, the resulting FSM is suitable to your task.  If you can't, you should probably rethink your logic.

Comment: How can I state that for all of the rest possibilities we stay in the current state? (I usually draw a pointer pointing both edges to the same state and I write the condition that I want to emphasize {meaning not all of them} ).

Comment: Just make an arrow such as a state points to itself under the default set of events.  Consider state 3 on [this example](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/v3ch1/fsm3-reject.gif).

Comment: I think we're getting... our signals crossed :) . I updated the question with a code example to be more clear.

Comment: Why do my signals conflict? I use ordering in my code (if-else if-else statements).

Comment: xbug is trying to make your state diagram completely deterministic by fully specifying the conditions for each arc. Ie, if `x` and `z` are true, both the arcs to `b2` and `b3` are satisfied so you dont know which to follow. Ideally, this is never the case, so xbug wants to add more logic to ensure no two arcs (even a self arc) are both true for any combination of inputs.

Comment: However, while this is typically fine for small examples, larger FSMs with more complicated potential overlap makes this a bit impractical imo. I dont mind the MATLAB Stateflow solution to this for prioritizing arcs ( http://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ug/implicit_ordering_by_angular_position_source_state.png ). They add numbers to the arcs to illustrate priority. I feel this is more practical than adding a ton of not terms, though others may disagree.

Comment: @Unn + xbug: I'm trying to make the diagramm reflect the code, not the other way around. The purpose should be that if I pick a random colleague and show him/her the diagram, he/she should be able to understand that the code that would be written is not a NFA but a DFA. Unn's sollution is approaching the desired result but I'm not sure if that method is widely recognized ( I personally love it but that's not the point :) ).

Comment: @user2692669 Having it be DFA will reflect the code (implicit in the else if is that `x && y` was false). However, if you want is simple, the Stateflow solution is probably your best bet. Im also unsure how instantly recognizable it is; but its pretty easy to understand once you realize your arcs are not mutually exclusive and try to figure out which arc to take.

Comment: @user2692669: You have to remember that you only enter an else block if the condition is false, hence the first condition being `(x & y)` means the second condition is `(x & z) & !(x & y)`. That is simplified to `(x & !y & z)`. In the same way the final condition is `x & !(x & y) & !(x & z)` or `(x & !y & !z)`

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question with `SystemVerilog`, I just wanted to mention an alternative way of describing your next state logic:

```
always_comb begin
  case (states)
    a1: 
        priority casez ({x,y,z})
         3'b11?:  next_state = b1; // x && y
         3'b1?1:  next_state = b2; // x && z
         3'b1??:  next_state = b3; // x
         default: next_state = a1; 
        endcase
  endcase
end
```

Also, the commonly used state diagram does not specify priority, so you need to completely specify the transition conditions as in xbug's answer. But I don't see why you can't extend this notation, for example, mark each arc with labels `1, 2, 3, and 4`, where lower numbers indicate higher priority.

Comment: I can't test the code right now, but I think you summed up the hole topic.
P.S. I think xbug should get the green tick, is it ok with you?